# I'm struggling to get my program to return specific information from my API

Tags: ruby, api, command-line-interface, net-http

I'm building a CLI using API and my intent is to get the program to return a list of Episodes and then the user can select an Episode # and the application will give out details about that specific episode including the title, description, writer, director and air date. I'm able to get the numbered list of episodes, however I'm struggling with returning the details. I'm getting the following:

```
Type the episode number you want more information on.
2
here are some details
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe14494eb20>
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe14494c280>
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe144957310>
```

this is the method running the details

```
def print_details(episode)
    puts "here ae some details"
    puts EpisodeIndex::Episode.find
  end
```

and this is my Episode class

```
class EpisodeIndex::Episode

   @@all = []
   
   def initialize(title_hash)
      title_hash.each do |key, value|
         self.class.attr_accessor key.to_s
         self.send("#{key}=", value)   
            end
    
      @@all << self
   end

   def self.all
      @@all
   end

   def self.find
      self.all
   end
end
```

The API I'm using is here:
https://www.officeapi.dev/api/episodes/

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
def print_details(episode)
    puts "here are some details"
    EpisodeIndex::Episode.find.each { |ep| puts ep.attributes }
  end
```

see if that helps you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're seeing is a list of `Episode` objects, which is fine, but by default it's showing you the object class and the object_id.  If you want a friendly output of the objects, create an `inspect` method.

```
class EpisodeIndex::Episode

   @@all = []
   attr_accessor :attributes
   
   def initialize(title_hash = {})
      self.attributes = title_hash.keys
      title_hash.each do |key, value|
         self.class.send(:attr_accessor, key.to_s)
         self.send("#{key}=", value)   
       end
    
      @@all << self
   end

   def inspect
     string = "Episode, details: "
     string << self.attributes.map { |a| "#{a}: #{send(a)" }
     string
   end

   def self.all
      @@all
   end

   def self.find
      self.all
   end
end
```

Now when you show the "details" you won't just get the object type and object ID, instead you'll get a human readable string of the episode and its details.